# Channel added to TvContract is invalid, while adding to Android TV using TIF?

Tags: android, android-tv, television

I tried adding channels to Default TV App in Android TV using TV Input Framework. Channels are getting added by specifying mandatory params. But the Channel is getting ignored and it shows message,

`com.google.android.tv E/ChannelDataManager: Ignoring an incoming channel with invalid input id.`

Any Ideas about why this happens and how to mitigate it?

Comment: Please share your Android TV Input Framework implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set correct input id (`TvContract.Channels.COLUMN_INPUT_ID`) which You get with intent for setup activity.

Input id looks like *applicationId/classNameRegisteredAsInputService*, where

- *applicationId*: com.company.myapp
- *classNameRegisteredAsInputService* - class you specify in manifset as service with `android.permission.BIND_TV_INPUT`: com.company.myapp.tvinput.service.IptvTvInputService